# using .foreach to remove one array from another

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach

I was attempting to use .forEach to remove the contents of one array(ignore) from another array(input).

As an example in the below I would expect the input array to contain "b" and "h" however it contains "g" and "h" when I run this.

curious why I am not getting my expected results and if this is a good method.

```
var input = ["a", "b", "g", "h"],                                               
    ignore = ["b", "h"];                                                        

var newInput = function(element, index, array){                                 
    if (input.indexOf(ignore[index]) > -1){                                     
       input.splice((ignore[index]), 1)                                        
    }                                                                           
}                                                                               

  ignore.forEach(newInput);
```

Comment: can you share what the output should be

Comment: With ignore set as ["b", "h"] I am expecting input to contain ["a", "g"]

Comment: @imnothardcore : did you dry run your code? I did and same you given code will give you the **["b", "h"]**

Comment: `ignore[index]` is precisely equal to `element`, right? You can't pass the element to `splice`, you have to pass the position.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your conditionals with `input.indexOf(element) > -1`.

Since you are forEach-ing the ignore array, `ignore[index]` is the same as `element`.

And change splice to `splice(input.indexOf(element), 1)`.

`Array.splice()` takes index as first arguments, and you are using the element instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = ["a", "b", "g", "h"],
    ignore = ["b", "h"];                        

var newInput = function(element, index, array){
    if (input.indexOf(ignore[index]) > -1) {
       input.splice(input.indexOf(ignore[index]), 1)
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  added this
    }
} 

ignore.forEach(newInput);
```

but that code could be cleaner, e.g. `ignore[index]` is `element`

```
var input = ["a", "b", "g", "h"],
    ignore = ["b", "h"];

var newInput = function(element) {
    var index = input.indexOf(element);
    if (index > -1){
       input.splice(index, 1)
    }
}

ignore.forEach(newInput);
```

If you really want to impress the girls

```
var input = ["a", "b", "g", "h"],
    ignore = ["b", "h"];

var newInput = function(element, index) {
    ~(index = input.indexOf(element)) && input.splice(index, 1);
}

ignore.forEach(newInput);
```

I'll let you figure out that one liner :p

> mutliple deletions

```
var newInput = function(element) {
    var index;
    while (~(index = input.indexOf(element)))
        input.splice(index, 1);
}

ignore.forEach(newInput);
```

Comment: It's very confusing to provide the `index` parameter to the callback, when it is not needed and not used, and then redefine it to mean something entirely else. I supposed it's intended to avoid having to spend one line declaring a variable, but come on. Also, although the OP did not say so explicitly, it's reasonable to assume that he wants to remove **all** occurrences of an ignored element, not just the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead

```
var input = ['a', 'b', 'g', 'h']
var ignore = ['b', 'h']
var newInput = input.filter(function (el) {
  return ignore.indexOf(el) === -1
})
```

Note that `input` remains unchanged

Answer (score 1):

`Array#filter` is probably the best approach, but if you want to remove the ignored elements in-place, as I infer from your use of `splice`, you can do:

```
function ignore_elements(input, ignore) {
  var i = 0;
  while (i < input.length)
    if (ignore.indexOf(input[i]) !== -1) input.splice(i, 1);
    else i++;
}
```

By looping over the elements in the input, instead of `ignore`, you can more easily eliminate **all** occurrences of the elements to be ignored, not just the first one.

Comment: I have seen some discussion of people suggesting a while and for loop over foreach and filter. what advantages does it offer? Also I like your idea of looping the input to get them all. Not needed in my application of this but probably better practice. Thanks

Comment: There's no hard and fast rule. However if you're filtering or mapping then filter and map are typically more succinct and readable.